# Passing stored arguments to a python class

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing

I want to write a program that runs multiple classes. My code looks like

```
list_of_classes = [class1, class2, class3]

def run_class(class_):
    print("Running class ", class_.__name__) #All my classes have such attribute
    x = class_()
    x.doStuff()
    #etc

for class_ in list_of_classes:
    run_class(class_)
```

Problem is, that for some classes, I want to pass some arguments (which are optional). For example, let's assume that for class1 I want to pass the argument `iterations = 150`.

How do I do that? My first thought is to change the `list_of_classes` like so:

`list_of_classes = [(class1, 'iterations=150'), (class2, ''), (class3, '')]`

But how do I pass the second part of the tuple as argument?

I do not want to place the arguments directly in the list like so:

`list_of_classes = [class1(iterations=150),class2,class3]`

because I will not be able to use the `__name__` attribute in my function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```py
list_of_classes = [
    (class1, [], {'iterations': 150}),
    (class2, [], {}),
    (class3, [], {}),
]
for class_, args, kwargs in list_of_classes:
    run_class(class_, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This solution does not work. However, changing the second item of the tuple in dictionary actually works, given that we are passing the function **args. Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the feedback. I was reading your requirement in a very literal sense. I have now updated the solution to be more generic.